# How does the magento framework interact with the various codepools?

Tags: magento

Anyone knows how does the magento framework interact with the various codepools?

Comment: Despite the correct answer below, you need to know *how* this occurs if you want to pass the certification exam.

Answer (score 3):

Magento has three different codepools:

1. Community
2. Core
3. Local

firstly it includes Local code pool, than community and after that – core, which allow developers to override classes without changing core files.
The autoloader firstly checks the local folder, than community, than core and than lib. And this is a reason why you can put **Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php** in the local directory and it will be loaded instead of core class.